# How to count the predicates

Tags: prolog

I'm looking for a way to count the numbers of predicates.
Example:

%facts

```
has_subclass(thing,animal).
has_subclass(thing,tree).
has_subclass(thing,object).
```

% and I ask

```
count_has_subclass(thing,X).
```

% result

X = 3.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [**`findall/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) for this, and then use [**`length/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2) to obtain the length of the list:

```
count_has_subclass(What, N):-
    findall(X, has_subclass(What, X), L),
    length(L, N).
```

If it is however possible that `has_subclass/2` yields the *same* values multiple times for a given key (like `thing`), then we can use for example [**`sort/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) as a duplicate filter, like:

```
count_has_subclass(What, N):-
    findall(X, has_subclass(What, X), L),
    sort(L, S),  %% remove duplicates
    length(S, N).
```

Note that if `What` is a free variable, then you will count all yeilds of `has_subclass(_, _).` (optionally with a uniqness filter on the second parameter).

Comment: This is the accepted answer but using `setof` seems to be much cleaner, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56084240/10721357).

Comment: @User9213: there is a small problem with `setof(..)`: if it can not find a single item that can be satisified, then it will fail, so it can not return `0`. For example `count_has_subclass(blahblah, N)` will not return `0`, but `false`.

Answer (score 2):

For facts like your example:

```
count_has_subclass(What, Count):-
  findall(1, call(has_subclass(What, _)), L),
  length(L, Count).
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard `setof/3` is a better option as it allows easy definition of a more general predicate that can enumerate solutions when the class argument is not bound. For example, assume the following database:

```
has_subclass(thing,animal).
has_subclass(thing,tree).
has_subclass(thing,object).

has_subclass(animal,cat).
has_subclass(animal,dog).

has_subclass(tree,pine).
has_subclass(tree,oak).
```

And the definition:

```
subclass_count(Class, Count) :-
    setof(Subclass, has_subclass(Class, Subclass), Subclasses),
    length(Subclasses, Count).
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- subclass_count(Class, Count).

Class = animal
Count = 2 ? ;

Class = thing
Count = 3 ? ;

Class = tree
Count = 2

yes
```

If you try instead one of the `findall/3` solutions in the other answers, we get instead:

```
| ?- count_has_subclass(What, Count).

Count = 7
```

But note that this solution also have a sensible interpretation as returning the number of all existing subclasses when the class is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

To build a list just to count solutions seems 'old style', but in traditional Prolog there is only the DB (assert/retract) alternative to overcome the 'stateless' nature of computations. Indeed findall/3 and friends builtins could be (naively) rewritten by means of assert/retract. But something have shown up since the early 80's ages :). I illustrate with SWI-Prolog, but - more or less naively - all of them could be implemented by assert/retract. Of course, most Prolog implementations have 'non logical' (or 'imperative', or 'impure') facilities to implement such basic task, without resorting to the heavyweight DB interface - like [setarg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setarg/3)/3, [nb_setval](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setval/2)/2 and others...

I digress... library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) should be shown first:

```
?- aggregate(count, T^has_subclass(thing,T), C).
C = 3.
```

This lib is well worth to study, does a lot more than - efficiently - counting...
Another, recent, addition is library([solution_sequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)). It's not more efficient than setof/3 + length/2, guess, but interesting in its own. Counting is a bit more involved, and uses [call_nth](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_nth/2)/2:

```
?- order_by([desc(C)],call_nth(has_subclass(thing,T),C)).
C = 3,
T = object ;
...
```

Some far simpler [code of mine](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/blob/master/lag.pl), based on [nb_setarg](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=nb_setarg/3)/3 (and help from @false):

```
?- [carlo(snippets/lag)].
true.

?- integrate(count,has_subclass(thing,T),C).
C = 3.
```